# What is the css / html `root` element?

Tags: html, css, netbeans

I have just recently started using NetBeans IDE (6.9.1) and have used it to add a stylesheet to my site-in-progress.

To my surprise, one element was automatically added:

```
root { 
    display: block;
}
```

Looking around, I could find some information about the `:root` pseudo-class but nothing about the `root` element itself.

What is the `root` element and does it have any use?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There is no element *called* root in HTML. The html element itself is "the root element" (which is the term given to the element which is the ancestor of all the other elements in the document), but this would be matched by `html { }`.

However, see [the `:root` pseudo-class](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#root-pseudo) (with a colon).

Answer (score 14):

From here: http://www.quirksmode.org/css/root.html

> The :root pseudo-element selects the
>   root of all blocks in the page, ie.
>   the Initial Containing Block. In HTML
>   this is obviously the `<html>` element
>
> Test stylesheet:

```
 :root {    
     background-color: #6374AB;
    padding: 50px; 
 }
```

> If the :root
>   selector works the left and right
>   column of the page are blue, and the
>   white middle column is offset by 50
>   pixels.

Comment: Thanks, that´s what I found as well, but I was wondering about the `root` element that NetBeans inserted, not the pseudo-element.

Comment: Since there is no such html tag, and it does not appear to be documented anywhere that I can find it, I'm going to guess that it's meant as sample code to show you how css is supposed to look for newbies. All I can tell you is that it'sdefinitely in the template, and you can edit the template yourself if you don't like it under "tools - templates" and then go to the "Web" folder.  I wouldn't consider it a "bug" since it's obviously intentional.  More like an "undocumented useless feature".

Comment: I guess you're right, it´s not really a bug; I´ve changed the template so I won´t be seeing it again.

Comment: The `root` element they are outputting simply does not exist. How is it not a bug for a template to generate code that is invalid / non-sensical?

Answer (score 14):

root is a placeholder for any element in the stylesheet template of NetBeans IDE. It is like a dummy variable in calculus. Please put the cursor on y: in the `root { display: block; }` delete y: and type y. IDE pops up into the instruction window that gives valueable information. They conducts to such a meaning for the root as just a dummy variable. Examples are `em {display: inline; }` Additionally, root is the point where you begin, the deepest ancestor of the html tree with branches and leaves. So at the beginning you have a box by default and all branches and leaves follow that default unless you change their default display, when they occur, to other values such as, say, inline.

Comment: Amazingly, this is the only answer that actually _answers the question_. All the others read "root" as ":root", which the question does not ask about.

Answer (score 12):

### :root can be used to declare CSS variables

in case anyone finds this old question and needs the information, `:root` is often used in examples to declare *CSS Custom Properties* or "variables" that become available throughout the document, for example:

```css
    :root {
      --darkGreen: #051;
      --myPink: #fce;
    }
    
    section {
      color: var(--darkGreen);
      background: var(--myPink);
    }

    article h3 {
      color: var(--darkGreen);
    }
```

However, **any element** can be used as the selector for CSS variables (not just `:root`) so `html` or `body` will also enable any element on the page to access them. If anyone has a good reason for using `:root`, I'd like to know it.

#### References:

- [Using CSS custom properties (variables)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_variables) .
- [CSS Variables: Why Should You Care?](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/02/css-variables-why-should-you-care)
- [Let's Talk about CSS Variables (explains why `--`, not `$`)](https://www.xanthir.com/blog/b4KT0)

Comment: The `:root` psuedo-element has a higher specificity than the `html` element, therefore, it is preferable to set the CSS variables inside `:root` i.e. globally and above the `html` element—this is done for general hygiene over the cascade. Otherwise, yes, both `html` and `body` elements will pass on the variables down the tree as well as you have rightly pointed out.

Comment: *"The :root psuedo-element has a higher specificity"*  Shouldn't this read *lower* specificity? So that variables set on `html` overrule the ones set on `:root`?

Comment: Not according to [CSS Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/r/root/#points-of-interest).

Answer (score 4):

The `:root` element is the element who has no parents, so I guess that the only root element in HTML is the `<html>` element.. 
So when you use the `:root` selector to style, it will style the whole document.

(I found more information here: http://webdesign.about.com/cs/css/qt/tipcsschild.htm and here: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_root.asp).

Answer (score 4):

There is a difference between root and html, the root pseudo-class is a CSS3 entity, and does not affect older browsers (MSIE 8 or less, Opera 9.4 or less)

```
html /* for all web browsers */
{
    color:red; 
}
```

You have to put a colon before the word root as follows...

```
:root /* for CSS3 web browsers: Chrome, Firefox, MSIE 9+, Safari, Opera 9.5+ */
{
    color:blue;
}
```

If you used both of these CSS lines, MSIE version 8 or less (or MSIE 9+ when running in compatibility mode, which renders as MSIE 7) would show red text, most other browsers would show blue text.

Documentation and specs for 'root' can be found at the Mozilla Developer Network: [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:root](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3aroot)

Answer (score 1):

The `:root` selector allows you to target the highest-level “parent” element in the DOM, or document tree. It is defined in the [CSS Selectors Level 3 spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/2018/CR-selectors-3-20180130/) as a “structural pseudo-class”, meaning it is used to style content based on its relationship with parent and sibling content.

In the overwhelming majority of cases you’re likely to encounter, **:root** refers to the `<html>` element in a webpage. In an HTML document the html element will always be the highest-level parent, so the behaviour of `:root` is predictable. However, since CSS is a styling language that can be used with other document formats, such as `SVG` and `XML`, the `:root` pseudo-class can refer to different elements in those cases. Regardless of the markup language, `:root` will always select the document’s top-most element in the document tree.