# Creating CSS Global Variables : Stylesheet theme management

Tags: css, variables

Is there a way to set global variables in css such as:

```
@Color1 = #fff;
@Color2 = #b00;

h1 {
  color:@Color1;
  background:@Color2;
}
```

Comment: CSS hasn't got variables, you need to use a preprocessor.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7247202/how-to-use-variable-in-css

please read this thread

Comment: So easy to google it http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/blog/css-variables/

Comment: Thanks for the link to the spec.  I should mention that it has been updated (5 May 2014). It now uses `--red: #b00;` and (a more convoluted) `color: var(--red);` instead of the old `var-red: #b00;` and (a more straightforward) `color: var(red);`. Firefox 31, which will probably be released the around the beginning of August 2014, has already been modified to reflect the new specs. It is the first (and currently only) browser to list support as standard. The partial/hacked support was removed from Chrome's blink engine (pending some rewrites), but it appears that WebKit (v.528+) has support.

Answer (score 182, accepted):

*Latest Update: **16/01/2020***

## CSS Custom Properties (Variables) have arrived!

#### It's 2020 and time to officially roll out this feature in your new applications.

---

**Preprocessor *"NOT"* required!**

There is a lot of repetition in CSS. A single color may be used in several places.

For some CSS declarations, it is possible to declare this higher in the cascade and let CSS inheritance solve this problem naturally.

For non-trivial projects, this is not always possible. By declaring a variable on the `:root` pseudo-element, a CSS author can halt some instances of repetition by using the variable.

### How it works

Set your variable at the top of your stylesheet:

**CSS**

Create a root class:

```
:root {
}
```

Create variables (-- *[String]* : *[value]*)

```
:root {
  --red: #b00;
  --blue: #00b;
  --fullwidth: 100%;
}
```

Set your variables anywhere in your CSS document:

```
h1 {
  color: var(--red);
}
#MyText {
  color: var(--blue);
  width: var(--fullwidth);
}
```

---

### BROWSER SUPPORT / COMPATIBILITY

See [caniuse.com](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-variables) for current compatability.

[image: ![supported browsers]

---

**Firefox:** Version **31**+ *(Enabled by default)*

Supported since **2014** *(Leading the way as usual.)*

<kbd>[More info from Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_variables)</kbd>

---

**Chrome:** Version **49**+ *(Enabled by default)*.

Supported since **2016**

---

**Safari/IOS Safari:** Version 9.1/9.3 *(Enabled by default)*.

Supported since **2016**

---

**Opera:** Version **39**+ *(Enabled by default)*.

Supported since **2016**

---

**Android:** Version **52**+ *(Enabled by default)*.

Supported since **2016**

---

**Edge:** Version **15**+ *(Enabled by default)*.

Supported since **2017**

CSS Custom Properties landed in Windows Insider Preview build 14986

---

**IE:** When pigs fly.

It's time to finally let this ship sink. No one enjoyed riding her anyway. ☺

---

**W3C SPEC**

Full specification for upcoming CSS variables

<kbd>[Read more](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-variables/)</kbd>

---

#### TRY IT OUT

A fiddle and snippet are attached below for testing:

***(It will only work with supported browsers.)***

[***DEMO FIDDLE***](http://jsfiddle.net/5hCtL/90/)

```css
:root {
  --red: #b00;
  --blue: #4679bd;
  --grey: #ddd;
  --W200: 200px;
  --Lft: left;
}
.Bx1,
.Bx2,
.Bx3,
.Bx4 {
  float: var(--Lft);
  width: var(--W200);
  height: var(--W200);
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid var(--red);
}
.Bx1 {
  color: var(--red);
  background: var(--grey);
}
.Bx2 {
  color: var(--grey);
  background: black;
}
.Bx3 {
  color: var(--grey);
  background: var(--blue);
}
.Bx4 {
  color: var(--grey);
  background: var(--red);
}
```

```html
<p>If you see four square boxes then variables are working as expected.</p>

<div class="Bx1">I should be red text on grey background.</div>
<div class="Bx2">I should be grey text on black background.</div>
<div class="Bx3">I should be grey text on blue background.</div>
<div class="Bx4">I should be grey text on red background.</div>
```

Comment: Even now preprocessors are still the way forward until everyone starts using modern browsers.

Comment: @BlueEyesWhiteDragon Unfortunately this is the nature of web development and as some user still use IE6 it could be another ten years before the approach is practical. It is our duty as developers to push browser updating to users wherever it is practical. People will continue to use outdated browsers as long as we continue to support them!

Comment: @Obsidian I dropped IE 8 & 9 support a while back, IE 10 seems modern enough to still support however...

Comment: I wonder why don't they allow us to declare variables with `var(test)` then use those variables along with a special character, may be something like `@test` or `$test`. Woundn't it be more convenient?

Comment: @Tresdin Yes it would be more convenient. The problem is CSS has already allocated both of those symbols for other uses along with nearly all special characters. I believe double hyphen(--) was chosen because a new declaration was required.

Comment: @Obsidian The actual problem is that you have to write `var(...)` anytime you want to use a variable. I think that's terribly inconvenient. Your point makes sense though.

Comment: @Tresdin This was my thinking too. The initial spec was simply --var but they changed it. I can only assume there was a good reason. Hopefully the time that will be saved when we can actually use variables will be worth it!  :)

Comment: IE: It's never going to happen.  

Comment: Am I allowed to use :root in several css files and does every work.
And what if a value is declared in two seperade :root declarations twice?

Comment: @CAoT I havn't tested but I suspect several root classes would be fine, following specificity rules.

Answer (score 32):

You can't create variables in CSS right now. If you want this sort of functionality you will need to use a CSS preprocessor like [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/) or [LESS](http://lesscss.org/). Here are your styles as they would appear in SASS:

```
$Color1:#fff;
$Color2:#b00;
$Color3:#050;

h1 {
    color:$Color1;
    background:$Color2;
}
```

They also allow you to do other (awesome) things like nesting selectors:

```
#some-id {
    color:red;

    &:hover {
        cursor:pointer;
    }
}
```

This would compile to:

```
#some-id { color:red; }
#some-id:hover { cursor:pointer; }
```

Check out the [official SASS tutorial](http://sass-lang.com/tutorial.html) for setup instructions and more on syntax/features. Personally I use a Visual Studio extension called [Web Workbench by Mindscape](http://www.mindscapehq.com/products/web-workbench) for easy developing, there are a lot of plugins for other IDEs as well.

### Update

As of July/August 2014, Firefox has implemented the [draft spec](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-variables/) for CSS variables, here is the syntax:

```
:root {
  --main-color: #06c;
  --accent-color: #006;
}
/* The rest of the CSS file */
#foo h1 {
  color: var(--main-color);
}
```

Comment: Thanks will take a look. What is the cross browser compatibility?

Comment: Well it compiles to CSS, so you write it (.scss file), build it (into a .css file) and then include it in your application just like a regular stylesheet. So compatibility is as good as CSS :) I highly recommend it, it makes writing CSS so much more fun.

Comment: @DanielImms is on fire this week. CSS variables are coming but how long will IE take to implement them.

Comment: @Christopher well, IE11 maybe.. As for when we would be able to use them though... I hope MS change their release cycle and start doing silent updates soon.

Answer (score 7):

It's not possible using CSS, but using a CSS preprocessor like [less](http://lesscss.org) or [SASS](http://sass-lang.com).

Comment: A processor is not needed, see @Obsidian's answer

Answer (score 4):

Try SASS http://sass-lang.com/ or LESS http://lesscss.org/

I love SASS and use it for all my projects.

Answer (score 4):

I do it this way:

**The html:**

```
<head>
    <style type="text/css"> <? require_once('xCss.php'); ?> </style>
</head>
```

**The xCss.php:**

```
<? // place here your vars
$fntBtn = 'bold 14px  Arial'
$colBorder  = '#556677' ;
$colBG0     = '#dddddd' ;
$colBG1     = '#44dddd' ;
$colBtn     = '#aadddd' ;

// here goes your css after the php-close tag: 
?>
button { border: solid 1px <?= $colBorder; ?>; border-radius:4px; font: <?= $fntBtn; ?>; background-color:<?= $colBtn; ?>; }
```

Comment: I like this idea but it requires using PHP on your server, which may not always be possible (for example, GitHub pages).

Answer (score 2):

You will either need LESS or SASS for the same..

But here is another alternative which I believe will work out in CSS3..

http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/blog/css-variables/

Example :

```
 :root {
    -webkit-var-beautifulColor: rgba(255,40,100, 0.8);
    -moz-var-beautifulColor: rgba(255,40,100, 0.8);
    -ms-var-beautifulColor: rgba(255,40,100, 0.8);
    -o-var-beautifulColor: rgba(255,40,100, 0.8);
    var-beautifulColor: rgba(255,40,100, 0.8);
 }
  .example1 h1 {
    color: -webkit-var(beautifulColor);
    color: -moz-var(beautifulColor);
    color: -ms-var(beautifulColor);
    color: -o-var(beautifulColor);
    color: var(beautifulColor);
 }
```