# Using global variables in HTML/CSS, is it possible?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Let me try and explain what I mean here....
I have a lot of images on my page, and different paths where they are stored.

```
<img src="what/ever/folder/pic01.jpg">
<img src="and/even/longer/path/name/pic09.jpg">
<img src="what/ever/folder/pic01.jpg">
<img src="and/even/longer/path/name/pic09.jpg">
```

etc... they are scattered all over the long page

Would it be possible with CSS or HTML or..  to make a variable containing each path, and then use that in the HTML?

```
PATH01 = 'what/ever/folder/'
PATH02 = 'and/even/longer/path/name/'
```

And then do the images, styles etc..

```
<img src={PATH01}"pic01.jpg">
```

Or something like that?   (am I making any sense?`hehe)

Comment: Neither HTML nor CSS has any concept of a variable. You can do this with "templating" solutions (either server-side templating or client-side templating) like Handlebars. Also possible client-side with `document.write`, but it isn't pretty. :-) Note that client-side templating will rely on JavaScript.

Comment: This might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15831657/creating-css-global-variables-stylesheet-theme-management

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> HyperText Markup Language, commonly abbreviated as HTML, is the
>   standard markup language

This means that here are no vars in html. But there a lot of html server-side processors like `php`,`node.js` etc which can give you result you are looking for.

**PHP example:**

```
<?php
$path01 = 'some/path/';
?>

<img src="<?=$path01?>pic01.jpg">
<br/>
<img src="<?php echo $path01?>pic01.jpg">
```

Answer (score 2):

good question, `<base>` is what you are looking for

> Specify a default URL and a default target for all links on a page

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_base.asp

in your case

`<img src="what/ever/folder/pic01.jpg">`

can be written in

```
<base href="http://whatever.com/what/ever/folder" />
<img src="pic01.jpg">
```

but `<base>` is a unique element in single page, which means you can have only **one** ENV variable set.

p.s. 99% of time we use html template system (php, jsp or react.js, handlebars) to solve this kind of problem in real life

Answer (score 0):

No you can't do that using purely HTML or CSS. You could however do something like that using javascript or the server language of your choice.