# CSS global variable change with js

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
@Color1 = #fff;
@Color2 = #b00;

h1 {
  color:@Color1;
  background:@Color2;
}
```

How can i change `@Color1` and `@Color2` with JS? This is my example code.

or

```
.chat-wrapper .chat-message.chat-message-sender .chat-message-wrapper:before {
    right: -20px;
    border-left-color: #8AC0D9;
}
```

How can I reach the border-left-color JavaScript code? I have a dynamically changing color value. I have to apply this. How can I do it ?

**EDIT**

*main.css* // this my css file @Álvaro-gonzález

```
.chat-wrapper .chat-message.chat-message-sender .chat-message-wrapper,
.chat-wrapper .chat-message.chat-message-sender .chat-message-content {
    float: right;
}
.chat-wrapper .chat-message.chat-message-sender .chat-message-wrapper:before {
    right: -20px;
    border-left-color: #8AC0D9;
}
```

Comment: I don't think this is supported yet... You may use LESS for this.

Comment: I don't think this is pure CSS. You're probably using some CSS preprocessor. If that's the case, the browser does not even see the original code, just the *generated* CSS. Please update the question to reflect the missing information.

Comment: What is `@Color1`?

Comment: Example code @torazaburo

Comment: This is not how CSS works. You do not change property values in CSS rules. Instead, you add classes to elements so the right rule is selected. The only thing JS needs to do is add or remove the necessary classes. This is basic CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15831657/creating-css-global-variables-stylesheet-theme-management) is the answer to your question.
So if you want to change value of any variable from linked question, you nee to do something like:

```
document.styleSheets[0].rules[0].style.setProperty("--red", "#FF0000");
```

Of course indexes of arrays must be double checked of iterated for finding corresponding selector

Comment: @forguta Did you just copy the pseudo-code from that other question and pretended that it's working CSS??

Comment: it's hardly ever a good idea, and hardly ever necessary. to mutate the style sheet like this.

Comment: I try not to discuss an entire idea. There is a question and here is an answer. It's pretty simple.