# Can I use global variables inside CSS proprety

Tags: javascript, css, dom, css-selectors

I know this works `left: var(--mouse-x);` you can update this values using JS which it's my goal here. My situation is a bit different, see I am trying to create an animation and I need to dynamically changes values in this line

```
clip-path: polygon(var(clip1) 0, 100% 1%, 100% 100%, 50% 100%);
```

Here's my attempt

```
 let root = document.documentElement;
 root.style.setProperty('clip1', e.clientY + "%");
```

The error is values are not set maybe because that variable is nested right there. Any suggestion?

Comment: it's should be `--clip1`.The naming convention is important

Comment: That's right, totally forget naming! thank you

Answer (score 0):

Should be:

`clip-path: polygon(var(--clip1) 0, 100% 1%, 100% 100%, 50% 100%);`

Look here:

> [Creating CSS Global Variables : Stylesheet theme management](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15831657/creating-css-global-variables-stylesheet-theme-management)