# Font-Family Change throughout the all pages in Angular application

Tags: css, angular

How to change the 'Font-Family' of an Angular application that applies to each element used throughout the application?

Example:
In CSS:

```css
p {
  font-family: Calibri, sans-serif
}
```

```html
<p>Calibri</p>
<label>Default</label>
```

Comment: Not sure I understand your question...you want to set a global font-family? Then do it in a global stylesheet and add it to `body`.

Comment: Yes. How to do?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using a third-party library you need to use ng-deep that gives you access to manipulates DOM elements.

In SCSS:

```
::ng-deep body {
font-family: 'Calibri', sans-serif;
}
```

if you don't have third party library, just use body tag.

In CSS:

```
body {
font-family: 'Calibri', sans-serif;
}
```

Comment: I want to use the same font through out the application.

Comment: you may find your answer here. try **root** as mentioned. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15831657/creating-css-global-variables-stylesheet-theme-management)

Comment: @envereren I had the same requirement and root did not help. When I used * it worked, fyi

Answer (score 0):

The font-family CSS property specifies a prioritized list of one or more font family names and/or generic family names for the selected element.

Example:

```css
.testfont{
 font-family: 'Comic Sans MS',  sans-serif;
 }
```

```html
<div class="testfont"> abcdefg (changed by class)</div>
<div class="default"> abcdefg (default cause not changed)</div>
```

Care: The style only applies to the class(es) you apply it to.

To apply it to each element use it in body:

```css
body{
 font-family: 'Comic Sans MS',  sans-serif;
 }
```

```html
<div class="testfont"> abcdefg (changed by body)</div>
<div class="default"> abcdefg (changed by body :D)</div>
```

Comment: I want to use the same font through out the application.