# How to apply the styles for one variable

Tags: css, variables

I have one variable var result,in this variable I was stored one text-box value,I want to apply the styles for that variable.How to apply styles for variable.Any one help me please.

Comment: No idea what you're talking about. CSS has no notion of a variable.

Comment: You can't style a variable... you could style that text-box thou

Comment: If you are talking about css variables see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7583076/using-css-variables . I suspect you mean something else ... but it is not clear form your question ... show us some code.

Comment: Ya,I want to give style for text-box text which is stored in variable.How to do this?Because i am beginner in css.So please excuse me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to set CSS style for text-box(HTML - input type - text) using java script
Try this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function changeStyle() {
       var cssString = "css style";
       document.getElementById("my_Element_id").style.cssText = cssString;
    }
</script>

<input type="text" id="my_Element_id" />
<input type="button" value="Change" onlclick="changeStyle()" />
```

Replace css style to your actual style.

Comment: it's not `<style type="text/javascript">`...`</style>` but `<script type="text/javascript">`...`</script>`

Answer (score 0):

You can't style a variable.

To style all textboxes you can write something like:

```
input[type="text"] {
  color: red;
}
```

If you would like to style one specific textbox, give it a class like:

```
<input type="text" class="my-custom-class" />
```

And style it with:

```
input.my-custom-class {
  color: red;
}
```