# Opera drags div to right

Tags: html, css

I've got a problem in Opera: When expanding the browser width to a certain amount, the div is jumping from the middle of the screen to the right side, near another div. Firefox and Chrome/Safari are working well and Opera just began making problems, before it worked too.

Here is the CSS Code

```
    root { 
    display: block;
}
body{
    margin: 0px;
}
.middle_frame{
    width: 600px;
    height: 600px;
    max-width: 600px;
    max-height: 600px;
    margin: auto;
}
```

and the HTML code

```
<body>              
        <div class="middle_frame">
                <div class="plz_list" id="plz_div">
                     blabla
                </div>
        </div>
</body>
```

Plus a before/after picture :-)

[image: how it should be and how it is until I expand]

[image: how it looks afterwards]

Comment: Have you tried `margin-left:auto;` and `margin-right:auto;`? worth a shot. I was faced with a similar problem, but with IE7. If you're going to try that, first remove `margin-auto;` or try an equal/fixed `px/%`.

Comment: Thanks for the input but both versions won't work. I am a bit frustrated since Opera was always no problem at all and is now coming up with this. When I remove the middle-frame and have another div with margin: auto I can reproduce the problem in Chrome, etc.

Comment: You're welcome. Have you tried removing your `body` style statement, or setting your margin for it to auto? So many different combinations.

Comment: See if this article will help you http://www.electrictoolbox.com/html-css-footer/

Comment: God, CSS can be confusing. I had to place a php function INSIDE the middle-frame div, no browser bothers but Opera (not talking about IE ;-). Thanks anyway!

Comment: Hm... probably something in the function, that Opera doesn't like.

Comment: I may be wrong, but the culprit might be 'root' css. More info here [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11092199/opera-drags-div-to-right](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3916824/what-is-the-css-html-root-element)

Comment: Which Opera - WebKit or Presto?

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you try create main div with margin:auto and width:600; and keep whole site in there? You will avoid those moves then and even if something like that.

Also you problem may be caused by float:left in menu on the top, once you expand browser to certain point, so you can fit menu and middle_frame beside each other opera is doin it.

Extra div for whole content will fix it